# Attaching external disk to aws cluster kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ebs

I have a cluster in AWS and have a deployment there. Now I want to attach an external AWS disk there. I am following the tutorial but didn't get how to indicate my disk there. Here is the code:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-ebs
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-ebs
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    # This AWS EBS volume must already exist.
    awsElasticBlockStore:
      volumeID: "<volume id>"
      fsType: ext4
```

Seems to me that I should indicate my disk at volume. Where should I take volume id then? And how connect it to my cluster?

Answer (score 1):

`volumeID`: This is the AWS volume that will be used.

You can use the AWS CLI to get the volume ID assigned to your instance.

CLI command:

`aws ec2 describe-volumes`

see the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-volumes.html) for getting the volume ID with using `describe-volumes`

for ex:

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "PersistentVolume"
metadata:
  name: "pv0001" 
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: "5Gi" 
  accessModes:
    - "ReadWriteOnce"
  awsElasticBlockStore: 
    fsType: "ext4" 
    volumeID: "vol-f37a03aa"
```

Comment: I created the volume, but how can I check was it applied?

Answer (score 1):

If the pod creation was successful with the volume attached (state of the ebs volume will change from "available" to "in-use" in AWS console), you could just do a `kubectl describe pod` and it should show up in Volumes with `VolumeID` similar to what you have in AWS:

[ebs-volume-info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuGxF.png)

Hope this answers your question.